# How to only get second row data from Sqlite?

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I am new to Python and I recently stuck in getting value from Sqlite. What I want is getting value only in second row of the table. This is the table [data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EM5ee.png). And I have tried this but not working:

```
        con = sqlite3.connect(database=r'ims.db')
        cur = con.cursor()
        for l in range(1,8):
            cur.execute(f"Select occolor{l} from ordercart limit 2")
            row = cur.fetchall()
            print(row)
```

This will bring both first and second row value. But what I want are only the second row value. Anyone help with this pls?

Comment: Without an "order by" the "second row" has no defined meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fetchall returns a reference to a list. Your query will return at most 2 rows. Therefore:

```
if (row := cur.fetchall()):
  print(row[-1])
else:
  print('Not found')
```

Doing it like this allows for the results being either empty or containing just one row

Comment: This is something to do in SQL and not in Python code. It does not seem to matter a lot for 2 rows, but imaging you want to get just the 10,000th row.

Comment: @KlausD. Thank you for your guidance. I am well aware of the implications of trying to use this technique for the Nth row. However, for once, I did read the question and this answers it in a reasonable way